# JSON parse from a Remote URL which requires a username and password in digest auth

Tags: ruby, json, authentication, digest

I have a URL which points to JSON output, however it requires a username and password through a standard Apache pop-up authentication box. I tried to access this URL from my Rails controller:

```
result = JSON.parse(open("http://user:pass@myurl.com/json").read)
```

However it isn't working. I have the following at the top of my controller:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'
```

I just get an error which says "ArgumentError, userinfo not supported. [RFC3986]".

I tried also the Basic Auth code, however it doesn't work since I'm using Digest Auth:

```
open("http://...", :http_basic_authentication=>[user, password])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [HTTPClient](http://rubygems.org/gems/httpclient) for this. It's another dependency but it makes RESTful requests with digest authentication super easy.

```
require "httpclient"

# foundational parts of your URI
base = "http://myurl.com"

# create a new http connection instance
http = HTTPClient.new

# set authentication on the connection
http.set_auth(base, "user", "pass")

# make your request
response = http.get("#{base}/json")

# parse the response's JSON into a Hash
JSON.parse response.body
```